# How to set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off' in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I find for the solution in Google, but still no luck. How to set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off' in my.cnf?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find out the answer :)

optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off'

Comment: Didn't work on mariadb  Ver 15.1 over a Debian 11